# dart asyncronous code - should i choose static or non static parameter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

i was building an app with Flutter and Firebase and I encountered the following problem:

I have a firebase helper class with within all the methods I need to use firebase realtime database and I will call these from the main function.

this is the firebase helper class:

```
class FBHelper {
  FBHelper._internal();

  static final DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('/');

  factory FBHelper() {
    return FBHelper._internal();
  }

  Future<void> initializeFirebase() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
    print('firebase app initialized');
  }

  Future<void> callPost(dynamic o) async {
    await database.set(o);
  }
}
```

and this is my main

```
void main() async {
  final _ = FBHelper();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await _.initializeFirebase();
  await _.callPost({"master": "1"});

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

if I mark as static the `DatabaseReference database` property there are no problems at all.

instead, if I avoid the static modifier I get this

**FirebaseException ([core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp())**

can someone explain me what I’m missing? do I have a wrong idea of how to use static?

Comment: Could you give your FBHelper a different name than _ and try again? I am even surprised that it compiles at all

Comment: My guess would be - static variables initialize only when you use them for the first time. Non-static (i.e. belonging to an object) get initialized when the object is created. If this is correct - when you remove static, your database variable will be initialised when you created an object - before you called initializeFirebase - meaning it would not hold a valid reference, since it does not exist yet. Edit: I found an article describing this, I think my guess was correct: https://www.technicalfeeder.com/2021/08/dart-understanding-class-initialization-order/

Comment: @jraufeisen why are you surprised?

Comment: _ is a valid variable name; just looks odd. You can usually see it in callbacks - something like (_) => - indicating that the mandatory argument will not be used inside the function.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I've also read the paper you send me and I think your guess was totally right!